# PHP script hanging after 15 minutes on IIS

Tags: php, iis, timeout, iis-express, applicationhost

I have a long-running PHP script, running on IIS (IISEXpress installed via WebMatrix 3.

For the first 15 minutes it works fine, querying the Amazon product advertising API, flushing output to the browser one line at a time to show its progress. Then it stops showing any progress.

I'm fairly sure the issue is not with the script, or Amazon API, because it reaches a different point of progress each time, but always stops at exactly 15 minutes (I have a time built into the script and elapsed time flushed to the page in the browser).

To prevent the script aborting with an error after 30 seconds I set:

```
set_time_limit(36000); in the script
```

I heard about IIS maybe having a CGI timeout after 15 minutes, and tried adding the CGI line to ApplicationHostConfig to override any default timeout. No effect.

```
   <location path="myAmazonScript">
        <system.webServer>
            <cgi createCGIWithNewConsole="true" createProcessAsUser="false" timeout="00:20:00" />
            <handlers>
                <remove name="PHP54_via_FastCGI" />
                <add name="PHP via FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe" responseBufferLimit="0" resourceType="Either" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
```

(If you're wondering, I set ResponseBufferLimit to 0 to enforce flushing.)

Elsewhere in the system.webserver section we have:

```
<cgi />
<fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe" monitorChangesTo="php.ini" activityTimeout="600" requestTimeout="600" instanceMaxRequests="10000">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />
            <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.4" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </application>
</fastCgi>
```

No other "timeout" values exist.

By the way, I can't run appcmd or access IIS setting by GUI, presumably because of being IISExpress. But applicationhost.config seems to work fine.

Any advice much appreciated.

Jonathan

Comment: did you ever solve this? i'm running into the same thing with unit tests... unit tests connection resets after exactly 15 minutes, but i can see from server logs that they are still running on the server for 16 minutes

Answer (score 1):

IIS-Manager on the server lets you manage the FastCGI settings. The defaults for activityTimeout (600) and idleTimeout (300) add up to 15 minutes exactly.

I added a zero to each of them and my 50-minutes-script went through like a charm.